# Can't connect Raspberry Pi to TV over HDMI

Tags: hdmi, connection, cable

I can't connect my RaspberryPi to my new Samsung TV over HDMI.
The RaspberryPi works with an HDMI to DVI cable with my normal 24" computer display.
But when I want to connect the PI to the TV over a HDMI cable there comes no content over the cable.
When I connect my notebook to the TV it works.

So the connection between Pi <=> PC monitor as well as between notebook <=> TV work.
What could be the problem that the connection between Pi and TV doesn't work?

Is the HDMI cable to long? It is 2 meter?
I have got the NOOBS OS on the PI and I configured the "configure.txt" as default:
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

Thank you for you suggestions
magicbasti

Comment: make sure that your micro SD card is inserted and that you are using the correct connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you are switching on the Raspberry Pi and then connecting HDMI cable to TV, then it may not work. For me it worked when I connect the HDMI cable to TV and then give power to Raspberry Pi.

Hope it works for you too.